# Biology Experiment Data (Hodgkin-Huxley)

Tags: physiology, neuroscience, bioinformatics, neuroanatomy, electrophysiology

I'm doing research into the Hodgkin-Huxley Model from an electronics/mathematics perspective and I'm looking to find actual numerical results from experiments on squid axons. I want to compare the results of the experiments to the curves produced by modelling the equations in MATLAB.

My problem is, that while there are an abundance of resources discussing the equations and methodology of the experiments, I am having great difficulty finding tabulated experimental data (not just numbers generated from modelling the equations).

As I am coming from outside the field of biology I would like to know are there sources of quality numerical data for these types of experiments? In particular I am looking for the data for Potassium Conductance vs Time, here is the plot from the 5th paper in their series of publications that earned them a Nobel prize:

[Hodgkin AL, Huxley AF. A quantitative description of membrane current and its application to conduction and excitation in nerve. The Journal of Physiology. 1952;117(4):500–544](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1392413/).

[image: Potassium Conductance vs Time]

Comment: You are looking for raw data? I suspect that none of these has been published. You could try to contact the authors and see if you can get hands on them. But I wouldn't be too optimistic.

Comment: There are various programs that can help to extract numerical data from graphs, I'd try something like this on the figure you posted. It is very unlikely that numerical data is easily available for such old experiments. The other option would be to look for very new papers about the subject, it is much more likely that such data is available for new papers.